# Ошибка “EOF when reading a line”

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

При запуске кода выдает ошибку *EOF when reading a line*...
Вероятно, что-то не так с 4-й строкой, но не понимаю, что именно?

```py
a = int(input())
b = 0
i = 0

while i <= a+1:
    s = input()

    if "rat" in s:
        b = 1
        i = i + 1
        print(i)
        
    if b == 0:
        print("-1")
```

Ввод:

```
3
baby will cry without a rattle
rodents mutated because of radiation
rotten eggs smell bad
```

Comment: а как запускаете?

Comment: И покажите ввод, который вы подаёте на программу

Comment: Видимо, нужно две отдельные строки подать на вход, а не одну

Comment: у меня все работет. каждую строку ввожу и делает вывод `i`

Comment: или это како-то онлайн сервис проверки заданий?

Comment: @Jack_oS да,это на Stepik

Comment: не был на Stepik, но обычно робот-проверяльщик ждет функцию, параметрами которой задаются тесткейсы... а можно ссылку на это задание?

Comment: @Jack_oS https://stepik.org/lesson/195451/step/3?unit=169727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто количество `s = input()` больше, чем нужно, вот оно и ругается...
Попробуйте так:

```
rows_total = int(input())
row_current = 1
is_rat = False

while row_current <= rows_total:
    s = input()
    if "rat" in s:
        is_rat = True
        print(row_current)
    row_current += 1
        
if not is_rat:
    print("-1")
```

Comment: спасибо,все работает!