# Как исправить ошибку EOF when reading a line? Вывод правильный

Tags: python

```
counter_zl = 0
counter_dobr = 0
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == 'добрый':
        counter_dobr += 1
        b = a
    elif a == 'злой':
        counter_zl += 1
        b = a
    elif a == 'Какой подарок?':
        if counter_dobr > counter_zl and b == 'добрый':
            print('серебряный шиллинг')
            counter_dobr = 0
            counter_zl = 0
        elif counter_zl > counter_dobr and b == 'злой':
            print('золотой шиллинг')
            counter_dobr = 0
            counter_zl = 0
        else:
            print('Ах, не знаю!')
            break
```

В ответ на этот код выдает :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/executing/solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
make: *** [Makefile:5: run] Error 1
```

Условие задачи:

Формат ввода
Вводятся строки: добрый, злой или Какой подарок? пока не будет введена пустая строка.

Формат вывода
Считается количество введенных строк разного типа и на вопрос о подарке выводится ответ.
Если строк добрый было больше, чем строк злой, и последняя строка добрый, то подарок серебряный шиллинг.
Если больше было строк злой и такая же последняя введенная, то подарок – золотой.
Если вопрос задан при неопределенном значении подарка, выводится: Ах, не знаю! и программа завершает работу.

После каждого вопроса строки считаются заново.

Comment: Тут стоящее твоего внимания решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241956/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: Где в коде обработка пустой строки?